# VB.net , i I need to populate a treeview from a Dbase table more faster with n levels

Tags: sql, vb.net, treeview, odbc

i need to polulate a treeview from a datatable that i got from a ODBC dbase.
the table has a CompID, ParentCompID and CompName, all strings. My table has about 4500 rows.
[sample of Dbase table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3AOy.jpg)

i found some code on the internet and adapt it so it works for me, i am able to populate the treeview but because of the children and grandchildren in the treeview it takes me around 7 minutes (what is not workable in my program). I am stuck with this for a week now ,cannot find a faster way. I am beginner VB.net programmer.
Anyone can help me out here or point me in a direction ?
Thanks.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TreeView1.Visible = False

    Dim PrSet As DataSet = PDataset("SELECT  CompID, ParentCompID, CompName, CompNo FROM [Component] Where CHAR_LENGTH(CompNo) = 14 AND (ParentCompID IS NOT NULL)")
    TreeView1.BeginUpdate()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    DataGridView5.DataSource = PrSet.Tables(0)
    For Each dr As DataRow In PrSet.Tables(0).Rows
        If (dr("ParentCompID")) = 1040965 Then
            Dim tnParent As New TreeNode()
            tnParent.Text = dr("CompNo").ToString().Trim() & " " & dr("CompName").ToString().Trim()
            Dim value As String = dr("CompID").ToString()
            tnParent.Expand()
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent)
            FillChild(tnParent, value)

        End If
    Next

    TreeView1.Sort()
    TreeView1.Visible = True
    TreeView1.EndUpdate()

End Sub
Public Function FillChild(parent As TreeNode, IID As String) As Integer


    Dim ds As DataSet = PDataset("SELECT CompID, ParentCompID, CompName, CompNo FROM Component WHERE ParentCompID =" + IID)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim child As New TreeNode()
            child.Text = dr("CompNo").ToString().Trim() & " " & dr("CompName").ToString().Trim()
            Dim temp As String = dr("CompID").ToString()
            child.Collapse()
            parent.Nodes.Add(child)
            FillChild(child, temp)
        Next
        Return 0
    Else
        Return 0
    End If

End Function
Protected Function PDataset(select_statement As String) As DataSet
    Dim _con As New OdbcConnection("Dsn=amos")
    Dim ad As New OdbcDataAdapter(select_statement, _con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ad.Fill(ds)
    _con.Close()
    Return ds
End Function
```

Comment: You do it gradually; only load the nodes that the user expands. 7 minutes sounds far too long for something as small as 4500 rows. Check you're not doing something silly, like querying the database 4500 times, or repainting/causing a refresh of the control 4500 times

Comment: Edit: oh, wait.. it does appear that you query the DB for every node. That might translate to thousands of queries. Put a `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + " begin query the db")` at the start of the PDataset and another one at the end so you can see how long it takes to query the db and how many times you do it. I suspect it will be "thousands of times" and "hundreds of ms" which all adds up. Sure I've answered a similar Q recently where all the data was in one dataset, and the Find method was used locally as the DS was iterated, to retrieve the TreeNode - was it your question?

Comment: @CaiusJard , i wil try to do that, thanks for the tip. If that's the case i need to find a solution

Comment: @CaiusJard,  between start treeview build and end treeview build  = 22928735 ticks and as you say alot of queries.(but 22928735 ticks is not that much if 10.000.000 ticks is 1 sec ? according to microsoft build :A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second. So it looks like a few seconds, but it takes minutes. i completely lost it..

Comment: So it took 2.2 seconds to build the tree.. where did the other 6mins 57seconds go? Did your program hang for about 7 minutes when you ended the update of the tree? Which part of the code is taking all the time?

Comment: If i knew, then my problem was solved... If i only place the parent nodes by comment out the  " FillChild(tnParent, value) "  it takes a second. if i don't, it takes minutes so the problem is for sure there in the Fill Child..

Comment: But that directly contradicts what you just told me when you said *@CaiusJard, between start treeview build and end treeview build = 22928735 ticks* - this means the whole operation including FillChild takes 2.2 seconds, then you said the problem is in FillChild and when FillChild is commented out it takes seconds, and when "commented in" it takes minutes - so how can it take minutes, but take seconds at the same time?

Comment: I know but it's true.. i really don't understand it, i placed the console instruction as follows to check the time, and i come around 2,5 sec . first line after button1_click and the end time after treeview1.visible instruction. I find a solution https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/679563/Fast-TreeView here but it's C#, i will try with that..

Comment: C# and VB.NET are the same thing, by the way...